# Image not showing up in php though inserted in sql database

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin

This is my code having a table with diff columns

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pcategories` (
  `categoryid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `catimage` varbinary(max) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (`categoryid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=14 ;
```

i want to insert image in "catimage'column. I have tried these 2.. kindly help me in fixing this

```
INSERT INTO `pcategories` (`categoryid`, `catimage`) VALUES
(9, 'p2.gif');


INSERT INTO `pcategories` (`categoryid`, `catimage`) VALUES
SELECT 9, 'Laptop Computers', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\wamp\www\OnlineBiddingSystem\images\p2.gif', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture
```

KINDLY HELP ME

Comment: What is the problem you encounter?

Comment: Take away "VALUES" in the final query

Comment: @Paul92: #1064 is the error with this
INSERT INTO `pcategories` (`categoryid`, `catimage`)
SELECT 9, 'Laptop Computers', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\wamp\www\OnlineBiddingSystem\images\p2.gif', Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture

The error pointing to **openrowset**

Comment: @Strawberry: When i have done that..
this is the error pointing to **openrowset**  **#1064**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `INSERT` tells MySQ it will insert values into two columns (`categoryid` and `catimage`):

```
NSERT INTO `pcategories` (`categoryid`, `catimage`) VALUES
```

However, you then proceed to add three values (`9`, `Laptop computers`, and an image):

```
SELECT 9, 'Laptop Computers', BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\wamp\www\OnlineBiddingSystem\images\p2.gif', 
  Single_Blob) as EmployeePicture
```

If you remove the second column ('Laptop computers') from the INSERT, that ought to do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO `pcategories` (`categoryid`, `catimage`) VALUES
SELECT 9, BulkColumn 
FROM Openrowset( Bulk 'C:\wamp\www\OnlineBiddingSystem\images\p2.gif', Single_Blob) 
  as EmployeePicture
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for insert

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO pcategories (categoryid, catimage) VALUES (9, 'p2.gif')";
```

Answer (score 0):

I save bulk images to db like this from php:

```
base64_encode(file_get_contents($imageName));
```